# How to get value from input and send to route?

Tags: php, jquery, html, laravel

I'm getting value in input in modal window, and I can't  use it for route

I tried to get value using jQuery, but it isn't work for me.

**Modal window HTML:**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="deleteValueModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form method="post" action="{{route('delete_value', $('#valueId').val())}}" id="deleteValueForm"                       
                        enctype="multipart/form-data">                        
                <label>Are you sure that you want to delete? 
                </label>        
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <input type="submit" id="valueId" name="valueId" value="" form="deleteValueForm" class="btn btn-primary">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).on("click", ".open-deleteValueModal", function () {
    const myValue = $(this).data('id');
    $(".modal-body #valueId").val( myValue );
```

IDE show me warning for jQuery code in form:

```
Expected: identifier
```

Laravel show me error for jQuery too:

```
syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' (View: ... )
```

Comment: You're missing closing brace, parentheses and semicolon in JS code. Put `});` at the end of JS code.

Comment: @rmalviya, I miss it here, in question. In program I have it

Comment: I can't find `.open-deleteValueModal` and `#valueId` in your HTML referenced from JS. Please share the complete code.

Comment: @rmalviya `valueId` is a name of `input` in modal footer. `.open-deleteValueModal` is opening modal `deleteValueModal`

Comment: Providing complete code can help your question get answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your named route `delete_value` looks like this `/posts/delete/{id}`. then you should render your form with default value (e.g. '0') as following:

```
{{route('delete_value', 0)}}
```

Now after the blade rendered the action should look like this:

```
http://localhost:8000/posts/delete/0
```

finally you can update the action value directly using jQuery as following:

```
$(document).on("click", ".open-deleteValueModal", function () {
    const myValue = $(this).data('id');

    // Optional validation
    if (parseInt(myValue) <= 0 || myValue == "") {alert('Some validation message');return;}
    // Get the default route
    var route = $("#deleteValueForm").attr("action");
    // Remove the current ID value
    route = route.substr(0, route.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
    // Attach the new ID value to the route
    route += myValue;
    // Update the form action with the new route
    $("#deleteValueForm").attr("action", route);
});
```

### Why you getting this error:

You passed an unexpected value `$('#valueId').val()` to the route() method, where an 'String', [PHP=>Array] or $(varible) was expected.

### Note:

You can change DOM element attributes only after is loaded.

Comment: Alternatively, you could define the route with an option id parameter. /posts/delete/{id?} That way you do not have to set an arbitrary default value when rendering the route in the html.

Comment: Sure! optional parameter would be easier, but optional parameter will add two patterns either `http://localhost:8000/posts/delete/1` or `http://localhost:8000/posts/delete` when required parameter will follow only one pattern `http://localhost:8000/posts/delete/1`. as also to the context the ID is required (delete requires the id)

Comment: I agree. It is a matter of opinion, I guess. You can set an arbitrary value which you would probably want to check for server side and throw an exception or check for a missing value.

Answer (score -1):

if i was you i would change the form action on modal open like this
`$('#deleteValueForm').attr('action', {{route('delete_value', $('#valueId').val())}})`

`$(document).on("click", ".open-deleteValueModal", function () {
 const myValue = $(this).data('id');
$('#deleteValueForm').attr('action', {{route('delete_value', myValue)}})
})`

that way the form already has a route its submitting to when u click a simple
`<input type="submit" value="Submit">` button

Comment: After the blade is rendered and displayed in the browser the PHP blade code `{{route('delete_value', myValue)}}` is useless and wrong in this context.

Comment: Oh yeah `var changeUrlResource = function(url, id) {
    return url.replace(/-?\d+/, id);
  }` that way they can `changeUrlResource("{{ route('delete_value', -1) }}", myValue)`